# Consequent <pre> blocks get wrapped to next line

Tags: html, css, pre

**I am trying to display a layout that should look like this -**

[image: Desired view]

My HTML looks like this -

```
<div>
    <pre>
        001
        002
        003
    </pre>
    <pre>
        Flight A from X to Y
        Flight B from Y to Z
        Flight C from Z to W
    </pre>
    <pre>
        A : 21:00    D : 21:15
        A : 21:15    D : 21:30
        A : 21:30    D : 21:45
    </pre>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like

```
div {
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div pre {
    overflow: visible;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

It all works correctly and I get my desired view.

But when screen resolution is low or when the window is resized to a very small size, the layout changes to this -

[image: Undesired wrapping view]

I don't want the entire `pre` blocks to wrap down vertically. I want the horizontal layout to stay as it was earlier and the containing div should activate its horizontal scrolling behaviour.

**Things I tried :**

As per other related answers on so, I have tried changing CSS property of the `pre` blocks to `display:inline;` but that did not change anything.

I tried wrapping the `pre` blocks into a container `pre` block of their own (so that they won't wrap down) like :

```
<div>
    <pre>
        <pre></pre>
        <pre></pre>
        <pre></pre>
    </pre>
</div>
```

But that didn't help either.

Comment: _“My HTML looks like this”_ - why? All design issues aside, that seems like a terrible way to convey the _meaning_ of this data in the first place. You seem to have _lines_ of text that each are a closed unit containing specific information in themselves - so why are you ripping this apart, to create such weird HTML to represent it in the first place?

Comment: If you have tabular data then maybe you should use a table. If you need a flexible layout (for example to collapse the third _column_ to a separate row when screen is small) then perhaps you should consider flexbox. Definitely not `float: left`...

Comment: This is **obviously** data that should be in a `table` or at least a table-based layout. I'm confused about why you chose the HTML your are electing to use.

Comment: Very valid points. But the layout was designed by someone before me and their JS-interactions are tightly bound to the fact that the 3 columns are continuously blocks of info in 3 separate sections. I cannot get into refactoring *that*.  I can only modify the CSS properties or add some layers to the layouts.

Comment: All this mention about tables has made me think of putting the `pre` blocks in a table with 1 row and 3 columns (though I know that is bad design). About to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
div {
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div pre {
    overflow: visible;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
    div {
    display: flex;
}
  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <pre>
        001
        002
        003
    </pre>
    <pre>
        Flight A from X to Y
        Flight B from Y to Z
        Flight C from Z to W
    </pre>
    <pre>
        A : 21:00    D : 21:15
        A : 21:15    D : 21:30
        A : 21:30    D : 21:45
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I will read up more about flex to see if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I removed the `@media screen ...` encapsulation and added the flex rules directly to the div CSS like this - `div { display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap; }` and it worked. Thanks.